# how start my running activity from status bar, app installed from google play

Tags: android, android-intent

Status bar notifications must open my running Activity, and do it perfect. But..

when i download my application from google  play, my status bar work wrong (start NEW Activity)... if i download application from my PC and install, status bar notifications work perfect. 
What i do wrong?
may be something wrong with my app Shortcut on homescreen? He appearance when i install app from google play, if i delete Shortcut and start app from menu, my app work perfect.

```
    /** Updates the notification. */
void updateNotification(String text) {
    Intent mintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    mintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    mintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            0, mintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),
            "Radio", text, pi);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}

/**
 * Configures service as a foreground service. A foreground service is a
 * service that's doing something the user is actively aware of (such as
 * playing music), and must appear to the user as a notification. That's why
 * we create the notification here.
 */
void setUpAsForeground(String text) {
    Intent mintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    mintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    mintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            0, mintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotification = new Notification();
    mNotification.tickerText = text;
    mNotification.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_name;
    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),
            "Radio", text, pi);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}
```

manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="fm.radio.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: android:launchMode=«singleTop» Save my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:launchMode=«singleTop»
```